# Simple SASS modules classes can’t work together for specificity

Tags: css, sass

I want to be able to not have to use `!important` and instead simply resolve by just using more specific selectors. Take this element for example:

```
<div>
    <p className={`${headerStyles.headerOuter} ${bodyStyles.something} ${otherStyles.another}`}>Test</p>
</div>
```

It uses three classes each defined in separate css modular files:

```
import headerStyles from ‘…’
import bodyStyles from ‘…’
import otherStyles from ‘…’
```

Let’s say that headerStyles.module.scss contains:

```
.headerOuter {
    color: blue;
}
```

bodyStyles.module.scss contains:

```
div .something {
    color: red;
}
```

And otherStyles.module.scss contains:

```
.another {
    color: green;
}
```

The `p` will have red text since bodyStyles is more specific.

But I want to be able to do this in headerStyles.module.scss:

```
.headerOuter {
    &.another {
        color: blue;
    }
}
// or .headerOuter.another
```

So that headerOuter and another can work together to be higher in specificity than bodyStyles to force the element to apply blue text. But the problem is that headerStyles and otherStyles don’t seem to be able to recognise each other.

How can this be fixed?

I’ve made a similar demo here, where the text should be black but it’s not: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-modules-react-forked-mxtt6 - see another.module.scss and the text should be black

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### From the codepen

The `color: black` selector is:

`._src_another_module__another._src_another_module__something`

While the actual element's classes are:

- `_src_test_module__test`
- `_src_sassy_module__something`
- `_src_another_module__another`

The second element's class contains "sassy", **it is different** from the selector, that's why it doesn't match.

You can check it with the DevTools. The `blue` and `red` styles are shown as overwritten, the `green` has more specificity, but the `black` one doesn't even apply for the element as shown in the picture below.

[image]

### Edit

I think there is lack of information about the actual tool behavior or just
a misunderstanding. The way it builds the name is `_src` + `_<file_name>` + `_<selector_name>`.

That being said:

```css
/* The final style from "another.module.scss. */

._src_another_module__something {
  color: red;
}

._src_another_module__bling {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
._src_another_module__bling button {
  background: red;
}

._src_another_module__another {
  color: blue;
}
._src_another_module__another._src_another_module__something {
  color: black;
}
```

Notice the `@import './sassy.module.scss'` has nothign to do with the black stuff, it just duplicates the style with a different naming.

```html
<!-- The final element with it's classes. -->

<p class="_src_test_module__test _src_sassy_module__something _src_another_module__another">
    test
</p>
```

Note: all this code comes from the codepen.

Text isn't black because you are including the selector `something` from the import of `sassy.module.scss` with the `${style.something}`, therefore the class will be named as `_src_sassy_module__something` (which is the red one).

If not yet, I encourage you to check the results with the DevTools often.

Comment: Sassy is just the filename and is not in the class name - the classes are {`${testStyles.test} ${styles.something} ${anotherStyles.another}`}. The point is you should be able to put `&.something` as the element has both classes, but I don't understand why it doesn't recognise it when the other selector is just in another file. It should show in your screenshot, but SASS doesn't create the selector properly

Comment: Well, it (`sassy`) actualy is in the class name. Let me update the answer to include more info.

Comment: oh I see what you mean. In that case is there not a better way of making the blue color display (from the .another selector) without using !important or creating another new class in the same .another.module.scss file? I cannot believe that SASS can't use two classes together from different files!

Comment: I'm not sure about your requirements but, have you tried to use just class names? I mean, not using them as objects. Just typing the `class="test something another"`, and simply importing the style modules as `import 'your.module.scss'`. I'm sure this way it'll work because naming doesn't change at all.

Comment: I'd rather use modules with objects. I'm surprised that there's no way to use them together when they're in different files

Answer (score 0):

```
<p className={`${testStyles.test} ${styles.something} ${anotherStyles.another}`}>test</p>
```

The reason it is not working is that the latest calssname which is **another** is being called and it dosent effect what you do with the previous classes that are added to the element which here is **something**. In the scss file **another.modules.scss** you are importing the **sassy.module.scss**, this updates the style on the class **something** but dosent effect the style on the latest class **another**.

```
`@import './sassy.module.scss';

.another {
  color: blue;

  &.something {
   color: black; // should be black
  }
 }
```